# Why does the result contain incomplete variables after `inner_join`?

Tags: r

I was trying to use `inner_join` to merge two data.frames. The problem I faced is that the merging result only contains variables in one of the data.frames.

I expect to see two data frames are merged in a way that unmatched observations are dropped and variables in these two are still contained. The two data frames in my case are named `cpds` and `gtd`.

I am pretty sure that I have two unique identifiers (in my case, `state` & `year`) and these two variable names are the same in these two data frames. Though the result indeed drops all unmatched observations; however, it only contains variables in one of the data frames.

Here is my code:

```
library(dplyr)
terdemo <- inner_join(cpds,gtd)
```

Then **R** responds the following messages including a warning one.

```
Joining, by = c("country", "year")

Warning message:
In inner_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y) :
joining character vector and factor, coercing into character vector
```

Could anyone explain why this warning message is triggered ?

**Note:** I use RStudio Version 1.0.136 and mac OS Sierra Version 10.12.3. Related package is `dplyr`.

Comment: What are the names of the two data frames?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, the two data frames are: Global Terrorism Dataset and Comparative Politics Data Set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably always explicitly join specifying the `by` parameter of the join, i.e.

```
terdemo <- inner_join(cpds, gtd, by=c("state" = "state", "year" = "year"))
```

However, this should not have anything to do with your current observations.  It is the behavior of `inner_join()` that for each pair of join columns in the two data frames being joined, only *one* of them appears in the output.  If you are perceiving columns being dropped, the the most likely explanation is that one or both of the join columns from one data frame have been omitted from the result data frame.

Comment: Thank you so much @Tim. I found that when I coerce the class of two unique identifiers to `character` first, then merge them by `inner_join`, the warning message disappears. However, the result still contains only variables in one of the data frames appear in the output. So what do you mean about "one or both of the join columns from one data frame have been omitted from the result data frame"? Could I coerce **R** not to omit columns in any data frame that I am going to merge? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Update your question showing the columns of the two data frames.  I'm not sure that what you are seeing is not to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the problem I had. The command `inner_join` has no problem at all, the reason why I could not find certain variables is that there are too many (>75) variables after merging so some of the variables could not be displayed when I use `View()`. You could use `name()` or `summary()` to check all the variables you have after merging. Hope this help.